# Office365 Click-and-Run alternative

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, sage

In our company we use Sage 100 that comes with the Access Runtime 2016.
We use Office 365 too. But there is an error that Click-and-Run and the normal installer not works together.

So is there alternative way to install Office365? Maybe with MSI?

Currently I do it with a registry entry, but on every Sage update I must first remove Office365 and reinstall after the update. So maybe you can help me with this

Comment: Are you the administrator for your company?  MSI only exists for VLK Office customers

Comment: This means I need to buy for the company VLK license? But all of the people have currently Microsoft standard license that I buy online when I create the user in der Admin Microsoft Interfaxe

Comment: The requirements for an MSI installer for Office are well documented. Do you have a specific question?  Your last typo has numerous typos and makes it hard to read.

Comment: Currently all users have a standard office 365 license. How can I change this to a VLK license to get the MSI installer?

Comment: You would have to purchase them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft 365 apps use **Click-to-Run (C2R)** installation technoloy, no matter it is for personal or for business, Access Runtime 2016 uses MSI installation technoloy, but they are both version 16.0.

Based on the article "[Supported scenarios for installing different versions of Office, Project, and Visio on the same computer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/install-different-office-visio-and-project-versions-on-the-same-computer)", Office C2R and MSI of the same version number cannot be installed side by side.

I suggest you choose one of Microsoft 365 and Access Runtime 2016 to install on **VM**.

Besides, Office products with **the same version number** and **the same installation technology** could be installed on the same computer without error message.

So, if condition allowed, you may buy volume licensed Office 2016 to replace Microsoft 365 apps, such as Professional Plus and Standard. (Please note, Office 2019 is not sutiable, as it use C2R technology too.)

Or could you change Access Runtime 2016 to be [Microsoft 365 Access Runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/download-and-install-microsoft-365-access-runtime-185c5a32-8ba9-491e-ac76-91cbe3ea09c9)? It uses C2R technology and could be installed with Microsoft 365 apps.

Office products with **different version numbers** and **different installation technologies** could also be installed on the same computer.

So, [Access Runtime 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358), its version number is 15.0 and it uses MSI technology could be installed with Microsoft 365 apps.